# Filtro manual via VBA com ultimos valores disponiveis

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, tabela-html, filtro

Preciso filtrar, via VBA, o 30 ultimos valores disponiveis em uma tabela dinamica mas no "filtro manual" que é o de linha...
É possível ler, no VB, os valores disponiveis no "filtro manual"?

Comment: Ei amigo, pode ser mais claro na sua pergunta?
Uso Excel a 12 anos e não sei exatamente do que se trata "filtro manual".

Comment: São os filtros de linhas e não os filtros da tabela dinamica em si..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abnerka,

Abaixo exemplo de código VBA que lhe permite diferenciar células ocultas de células visíveis. Células ocultas ficam com o valor de RowHeight = 0 no Excel.

```
Const _
    primeiraLinha = 4, _
    ultimalinha = 12, _
    colunaPrincipal = "A", _
    tudo = colunaPrincipal & primeiraLinha & ":" & colunaPrincipal & ultimalinha
    nomeAbaExcel = "Plan1"

Dim objetoLinha As Object
For Each objetoLinha In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nomeAbaExcel).Range(tudo).Cells

    If objetoLinha.RowHeight > 0 Then

        Total = Total + 1

    End If

Next objetoLinha

MsgBox Total
```

De fato admito que não entendi muito bem o que você realmente precisa.
Mas acredito que com esse código você possa adaptar e resolver o problema.

Para todos os casos, a tabela dinâmica fornece a possibilidade de filtrar os 30 maiores e 30 menores itens (se ajudar).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Segunda vou tentar,  muito obrigado.